# Checking feasibility of a system of inequalities with scipy

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, linear-programming

I have a set of pairwise constraints, like this:

```
a > b, b > c, c > a
```

and need to check if they are satisfiable (in the example above, they are not). This can be framed as a system of inequalities and solved with linear programming, for example with [scipy.optimize.linprog](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html).

The problem is, `linprog` uses `<=`, so it always finds the trivial solution where it sets all variables to zero. My idea is to re-write the inequalities as follows:

```
b - a <= -1
c - b <= -1
a - c <= -1
```

Is it equivalent to `... - ... < 0` system, though?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that all variables are constrained to be >= 1. Therefore the answer appears to be "yes", judging from the comments.

BTW, if you know of a better way to solve the original problem (checking binary constraints), speak up.

Comment: No, of course not. If $a = 0.2$ and $b = 0.1$, is it true that $b - a \le -1$?

Comment: @T.Bongers it is possible that the OP is looking for integer solutions only, in which case $a>b \Leftrightarrow a\geq b+1\Leftrightarrow b-a\leq -1$.  It really should have been stated however in the post Nucular...  And if you are *not* looking only for integer solutions, then as T.Bongers points out... no, it is not equivalent.

Comment: how is the original problem?

Comment: It should be less than or equal to 0.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: Your edit suggestion got rejected twice. It is extremely rude to invade another active user's posts with edits; instead, signal the errors in comments. If you push your edit suggestion a third time, you'll have to explain your behaviour to a moderator!